# I want to replace the linux distro(current ubuntu 18.04 lts) with elementry os 5.1

Tags: partition, grub2, dual-boot, elementary-os

I want to replace the linux distro(current ubuntu 18.04 lts) with elementry os 5.1

I saw many tutorials but here is where my question differs. I have two drives on my PC. One SSD and another HDD. SSD has windows 10 installed and first 837 GB is used as D drive on windows ans the next 93 GB is used as UBUNTU. Now there is another 512 MB partition sitting between these two.

[image: Current Disk Partitions]

I know a lot about computers and file systems and whatnot (so i don't mid approaches which involve CMD or bash), but I am not sure of that 512 MB partition. Whether it is important for UBUNTU or for windows, and I REALLY REALLY don't want to mess with windows OS.

Another thing I can do is, format the HDD while keeping the D drive files backed up on an external HDD, and then freshly install elementary OS on it, but that would be too tiresome, and also not a very challenging approach.

Also I would like to have GRUB whether it be the one from UBUNTU or a fresh install

I asked this on ask ubuntu community but they removed it as it wasn't related to ubuntu and more related to unix and linux community and I agree.

Comment: 512MB, according to your screenshot, is EFI boot partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out.
You start with normal installation, i.e., a live USB boot.
If you are changing the distro then the first option would be to replace Ubuntu(my case) choose that and then just continue.

Whereas if you are going to reinstall a distro then choose something else. There you have to format you disk partition which contained the OS which you want to replace or reinstall.To do this right click that partition and choose delete. Then again right click that partition and then choose it. Select ext4 as the file system and select '/' as the mounting and the continue.

The next steps are pretty easy.